# Select Radiobutton when Text equals value of Radiobutton

Tags: php, jquery, html

Is there a posibility to select 1 of 2 Radiobuttons with the same name but different values when text in a dropdown equals the value?

https://paste.ee/p/2iCjA Line 97

**I tried it with if-else:**

```
if($('input[name="anrede"]').val() == 'Herr')       
{
    $("#Herr").prop("checked", true)
}
else
{
     $("#Frau").prop("checked", true)   
}
```

"anrede" is the name of the Radiobuttons. "Herr" and "Frau" are the values/ids.

**Edit 1:**

The jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hfbxcr9m/11/    --> You need to add two entries with the different Radiobuttons. After selecting them I want that besides the name and surname the correct Radiobutton gets selected.

**Edit 2:**

Image for clarification: [link](http://www.image-hoster.de/preview.php?file=be0f23e9b95041a2716323d22.png)

**Edit 3:**

Updated the fiddle with english fields: http://jsfiddle.net/hfbxcr9m/11/

**Edit 4: Desired Output**

[image]

Comment: can you please create a jsFiddle with only the required elements

Comment: The jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hfbxcr9m/2/    --> You need to add two entries with the different Radiobuttons. After selecting them I want that besides the name and surname the correct Radiobutton gets selected.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/guradio/g2hd0g3v/4/ hopefully this will solve it

Comment: After editing the entries the Radiobuttons wont change to the right salutation.  Maybe the fiddle with updated to english helps: http://jsfiddle.net/hfbxcr9m/11/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('input[name="anrede"][value="' + selectedName + '"]').prop('checked', true);
```

or:

```
$('input[name="anrede"]').filter(function() { return $(this).val() == selectedName; }).prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: Both show no effect after I tried to implement it. Do I need to adjust the code?

Answer (score 2):

No need for `if else` condition here, try this code :

```
$('select').click(function() 
{
    var selectedName = $('select[name="docsApp.options"] option:selected').text();
    // unchecked all the radio button first
    $('input[name="anrede"]').prop('checked', false);
    // checked only radio with matched value
    $('input[name="anrede"][value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').prop('checked', true);
    // another rest of the code.....
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/11414Ljk/)**

Comment: I tried to implement the code but the Radiobuttons aren´t selected. Could this be because my options are not static?

Comment: your option are dynamic element?

Comment: Yes I add, edit and delete the entries. See it in this JsFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/guradio/g2hd0g3v/) from @Brownman Revival

Comment: What you mean by `my options are not static` ? Option from select?

Comment: In your demo the options are predefined( <option id='Herr' value='Herr'>adas</option>). But mine aren´t.

Comment: Got it. Option is not static, what about `select` element itself?

Comment: The select elements combine the radiobutton and the two text inputs. Maybe this Picture [link](http://www.image-hoster.de/preview.php?file=be0f23e9b95041a2716323d22.png) clarifies it.

Comment: very clear right now. What about if the name didt not match. Eg : johny, what sould be for his/her `vorname` and `nachname`?

Comment: If i click on an entry in the list on the left the vorname(first name) nachname(surname) appears in the text inputs for editing. So they should match always.

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/guradio/g2hd0g3v/)
I give your select an id and used it as select parameter

```
$('#select').click(function() {
  var selectedName = $('select[name="docsApp.options"] option:selected').text();

  if ($('#select option:selected').val() == 'Herr')

  {
    $("#Herr").prop("checked", true)
  } else {
    $("#Frau").prop("checked", true)
  }
```

Comment: Will this work with variable entries aswell? I tried using the form to add more entries but there it didn´t work.

Comment: can you update the fiddle so i can see what you mean

Comment: Could you just add two entries in your fiddle with each radiobutton selected?

Comment: Maybe this Picture [link](http://www.image-hoster.de/preview.php?file=be0f23e9b95041a2716323d22.png) clarifies it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="anrede" value=""/><br/>
<input type="button" id="new" value="new_function"/><br/>
<input type="radio" name="sex" id="Herr" value="male">Male<br/>
<input type="radio" name="sex" id="Ferr" value="female">Female<br/>

    $("#new").on("click",function(){
        if($('input[name="anrede"]').val() == 'Herr')       
        {
            $("#Herr").prop("checked", true)
        }
        else
        {
            $("#Ferr").prop("checked", true)   
        }
    });
```

Comment: It always selects the first Radiobutton. Even if it should be the second.

Comment: No,its not always selecting first....as you can see I have used "Herr" in my if condition.So if I enter any other value other than Herr in input box.It will check 2nd.